# From a list of tuples add one to each tuple element using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list and I would like to get a new list such that each tuple in position 0 has 1 added to it.  I can build a new list of tuples using loops but I want to understand how to do this with list comprehensions.
What I have:

```
in_list = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

What I want:

```
in_list = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuple is immutable type, so to increase the value at position `0`, construct new tuple:

```py
in_list = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4)]


in_list = [(a + 1, b) for a, b in in_list]
print(in_list)
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach similar to @AndrejKesely but just using the original list contents.  Note: You must create new tuples rather than attempt to change the original tuples since a tuple is immutable.
`[(x[0]+1, x[1]) for x in in_list]`